# Visual studio 2017 is not working, after stopping a template installer

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2017

I had started installation of Microsoft template for visual studio 2017,but I had to stop it before it was completed,now visual studio is giving error at startup " ***The setup for this installation of visual Studio is not complete*..**" also that template setup is not working it says " ***The extension manifest is invalid***".

Answer (score 0):

To repair Visual Studio, start the Installer from the following location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe
```

Once it starts, select *More*, and then select *Repair*.

[image]

In case of problems, see Microsoft's article
[Troubleshoot Visual Studio 2017 installation and upgrade issues](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2017).